# Change font-size in legend

Tags: r, plot, visualization

I have a legend in my plot, but I'm trying to increase the font size so it fit the legend-box. When I try to increase the `cex` as defined below. The box gets bigger, while the text is still small.

Code:

```
legend(0,16, c("Available vCPUs", "Added vCPUs (1 per iteration ) "),
 col=c('red', 'black'), cex=0.39, lty=1:1, lwd=2)
```

Excerpt from plot:

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**First approach:**

Try to set the font size before to plot the legend.

```
 x <- y <- rnorm(100, 0, 1)
 plot(x, y, type = "n")

## here you set the font size default to `x`, in this example 0.5
## save defaults in `op`

 op <- par(cex = 0.5)

 legend("topright", legend = "foo legend", pch = 1, bty = "n")
```

[image]

```
## here you set cexto 1.5
## save new defaults in `op`

 op <- par(cex = 1.5)

 legend("topright", legend = "foo legend", pch = 1, bty = "n")
```

[image]

**Second approach:**

Holding the `pt.cex` parameter to 1, while trying different values for `cex` **inside** the legend call. Remember to delete `op`.

```
x <- rnorm(100, 10, 4)
y <- rnorm(100, 10, 4)
plot(x, y, type = "n")

## I tried to feed cex with 1.5 and 0.5. The font size changes while the points remain unchanged.

legend("topleft", "Legend", cex=0.5, pch=1, pt.cex = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: I believe you misunderstood my question. My goal was to increase the font-size of the text in the legend. Since the font size is to small in relation to the legend. @Worice

Comment: Oh sorry, then play with   `op <- par(cex = 1.5)`. By change this parameter you adjust the size.

Comment: That is unfortunate. I edited the answer with a second approach. Give it a try and tell me.

Comment: Outstanding... it also works smoothly for the netmeta package

Answer (score 4):

You can use cex to determine font size, use bty='n' to indicate no lines around the legend, then draw a rectangle separately on the graph with rect().  For example:

```
with(data, legend(-10,7, legend=c("Name_of_Legend"), bty = 'n', col=c("red"), lty=0, pch=20, cex=0.75))
with(data, rect(-10,6.2,-3,7))
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can try using the 
`y.intersp` in legend, when the intervals between different text lines are reduced, you could increase text size without changing the size of legend box.

```
legend(0,16, c("Available vCPUs","Added vCPUs (1 per iteration )
"),col=c('red','black'),cex=0.39,lty=1:1,lwd=2, y.intersp = 0.3)
```